# Project Euler #23 Optimization

Tags: python, number-theory

Non-abundant sums

[Problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23)

A number n is called abundant if the sum of its proper divisors exceeds n. Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

I have tried several things and optimized my code as much as I could with my limited knowledge of coding. A few days ago I started learning how to code, and I found this page, (project euler), I deviated a little from learning and just started to code to try and solve the problems. So far I've managed to solve most of the easiest problems without taking a long time, but this one is taking too long in comparison. Sorry if my code isn't understandable.

```
sum_abundant = []
for i in abundant:
    for n in abundant:
        c = i + n
        if n > i:
            break
        if c < 28123:
            if c not in sum_abundant:  # if the number has already been removed, it won't remove it again.
                sum_abundant.append(c)
```

("abundant" is a list with all the abundant numbers.)
It isn't the whole code, just the part where I believe it takes most of the time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, your description that "my code isn't working" is not sufficient. How to you know it is not working--do you get an error message, is the output a number that is not accepted by the Project Euler page, or something else? Also, your title says that you want optimization but your text says that your code is not working--which is it? Finally, the philosophy of Project Euler is that you should not ask for help. If you cannot solve a problem, move on to another problem. If you ask for more specific help, such as for a particular line of code, we could help there.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it getting the right answer and you want to speed it up? Or is the answer wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that you could take is to decompose the problem into intermediate steps:

- Determine the proper divisors of all numbers up to 28123
- Select the numbers that are "abundant" using the lists of divisors
- Find all pairs of abundant numbers and flag their sums
- Select the numbers that were not flagged by the previous steps (those will be the numbers that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundants)
- Compute the sum of this result

here's an example:

```
# Create a list of proper divisora for all numbers up to 28123...

properDivs     = [ [] for _ in range(28124) ] 
for n in range(1,28124):
    for i in range(2*n,28124,n):
        properDivs[i].append(n)

# Select the numbers that are abundant (sum of divisors > number itself)...

abundants = [n for n,divs in enumerate(properDivs) if sum(divs)>n]

# Find all pairs of abundant numbers and flag their sums

from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
sumOf2Abundants = [False for _ in range(28124)]
for a,b in combinations_with_replacement(abundants,2):
    if a+b<len(sumOf2Abundants):
        sumOf2Abundants[a+b] = True

# Select numbers that were not flagged...

result = [n for n,isSumOf2 in enumerate(sumOf2Abundants) if not isSumOf2]

# compute and print the sum of the above result

print(sum(result))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to research some things to understand the code, hehe. I think I might not be ready to try to tackle some harder problems. Which way or method would you recommend to learn more about how to code? Is there a certain book, webpage, channel that you would recommend me? I would be really thankful if you could, and, again, thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't recommend any sites or book for basic programming because I learned on my own more than 40 years ago and it was very different then. I believe you're on the right track with your attempts at solving programming problems.  Programming is really just a bag of tricks you collect over the years.  You could also learn a lot by analyzing code produced by others. BTW: I changed `combinations` to `comibnations_with_replacement` in my example because it was missing the pairs that combined an abundant number with itself (e.g. 12+12).